# Automatically fill two lines per single entry

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub af_norm
    dim cardnum, userid as string
    dim i, j as integer
    Dim wb as workbook
    dim ws as worksheet
    dim datetime

    set wb = thisworkbook
    set ws = wb.activesheet
    datetime = now
    userid = environ("username")

    i = 2
    do while ws.range("a" & i).value <> ""
        i = i + 1
    loop
 
    cardnum = ws.range("C" & i).value
    if len(cardnum) <> 16 then
        msgbox "Invalid number."
        exit sub
    end if

    ws.range("a" & i).value = userid
    ws.range("b" & i).value = format(datetime,"dd mm yyyy hh:mm")
    ws.range("c" & i).value = cardnum
    ws.range("c" & i).select

End Sub
```

this codes are working as required.right now, what the code is doing is it accepts the value on the first row after the column header on column c, then automatically populates the user id and time.

But what I want to do is to automatically fill in the next line after I enter a value on column c.

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please provide a [mcve]. In the code you show it is not clear how `i` is defined. We need more background information and a description of what you actually want to achive versus what hapens. Please [edit] your question to improve it. Please also include where this code is located, looks like you are using it in an event?

Comment: thank you for the feedback. i have edited ny question and included the codes.

Comment: Just to be clear. What you want is, that if you write something in column C it should add userid and date in column A and B in the same line **automatically** right?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the current codes that i posted already fills up the data in the column ranges. but what i want to do is if i write something on column c,it will populate values on column a and b,then it will automatically fill the next row

Comment: Sorry still not clear. **When** do you want this to happen? When ever you enter something into column C (**automatically**)? Or when you push a button or something?

Comment: on my original codes, i put card number on c2 coz c1 contains the column header,so if i enter card num on c2, the formula for a2 and b2 will run, but it will only run if column c is not blank. what i want to do now is if i enter card number on c2, i should also have card number on c3,and the codes for a3 and b3 will also run. is that possible?

Comment: i have a separate codes on the sheet object and it just calls the sub for af_norm if target.column = 3 which is the column where i enter the card number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill column A and B automatically when C is changed then you need to use the `Worksheet_Change` which runs automatically when ever a cell in its worksheet was changed.

Then limit the code to only run if a cell in column c was changed (and exclude the header). We do that using `Intersect` as shown below.

Make sure you format column C as `Text` and not as `General` or number. Otherwise if you enter a 16 digit number into a cell (e.g. `1234567890123456`) Excel will turn it into scientific notation `1,23457E+15` which is `1234567890123450` and different from what you actually entered. So make sure this is handled as text not as numeric number!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2", "C" & Me.Rows.Count))
    
    On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS  ' ensure that if an error occurs events are always enabled!
    Application.EnableEvents = False  ' we need to disable events otherwise writing to cells will cause another event and eventually and endless loop of events
    
    ' only run this code if a change in column C (except header row) was made
    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        ' run for every cell in column C that was changed
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange
            Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
            If Cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then
                ' card number was removed so remove userid and timestamp
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "A").ClearContents
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").ClearContents
            ElseIf Len(Cell.Value2) = 16 Then
                ' card number was entered so write userid and timestamp
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value2 = Environ("username") ' write userid
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value2 = Now  ' write date
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").NumberFormat = "dd mm yyyy hh:mm"  ' format date in column B
            Else
                ' invalid number was entered
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "A").ClearContents
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").ClearContents
                Me.Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value2 = "invalid card number"
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
    
ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

Some notes to your code:

1. `Dim i, j As Integer` will declare `i As Variant` because in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer`, otherwise it is `Variant` by default. Also they need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than fit into `Integer`!
2. There is a much quicker way to find the next free cell than looping

   ```
   do while ws.range("a" & i).value <> ""
       i = i + 1
   loop
   ```

   usually people use something like below instead of a loop

   ```
   FreeRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   ```